# react-native maps not loading for android (blank map)

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

I've been stuck on this for a long time now and am starting to think perhaps react native maps cannot work on android emulator, as all the answers I find that seem to work are for IOS anyways.

I am currently using android emulator to run my app. Here is the code for a simple map...

```
class MainMap extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
  }
    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}
  />
  </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    width:150,
    height:150,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});

module.exports = MainMap;
```

The code seems like it should work, as I took it straight from an example. I even got my API key from google API and then added the following in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="api here"/>
```

Now, when I run `react-native run-android` the app seems to run fine, with no error messages. However, the app is blank. The `View` container loads fine, but its content `MapView` does not load at all. All I see is literally a blank screen.

Note that I also have Google Play services and Google API installed on my emulator too.

How can I debug this issue since I get no error messages at all? Can `react-native maps` even work on android emulator?

**EDIT**

I've been stuck on this for a long time now, and it's stalling me from being able to work on this project of mine. Because the nature of the question is difficult to debug, I am going to provide a github link to my repository in case anyone is willing to replicate the problem on their end and see what my issue is...

https://github.com/Bolboa/TTC-Mapping

All I need is for the map to load. The code looks like it should work, but the map does not load...

I am going to offer a bounty to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: try `container` style with `container: { flex: 1,   justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center', }.

Comment: @ubatin I tried this. It seems the map is simply just not loading at all...

Comment: did you try removing the signing on the api key in google api console?I mean the package name and SHA1 key.SOmetimes its the issue of debug key and release key.Am just asking if you considered this approach?

Comment: @ArpanSharma well my key is not restricted, so all I am given in Google API console is a random API key that I then included in my `meta` tag. So I think I am using that approach

Comment: @Bolboa did you try changing the key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give style to `MapView`.

Include

```
var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
```

in render method

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView style = {styles.mapcontainer}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          showsMyLocationButton={false}
          zoomEnabled = {true}
          region={this.state.region} >
        </MapView>
</View>
```

Include style

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
mapcontainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: width,
    height: height,
  },
```

Comment: @Bolboa : have you try this solution?

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy with other work, but I will try it today :)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, regenerating an API Key and updating it in:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="YOUR_ANDROID_KEY"/>
```

fixed it for me. Not sure how as both have the same settings.. No longer have the grey screen with Google icon!

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating a `styles` variable with `map` style but you are not applying that style to MapView.
You need to add the following line which will assign style to the MapView

```
style={styles.map}
```

so that now it looks like

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
       }}/>
</View>
```

also have a look at [troubleshooting](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps#troubleshooting) section  you missed to include the second part.
If even after adding the style you are not able to see the map there is a problem with your key.

Answer (score 0):

**Activate "Maps SDK for Android" and "Maps SDK for iOS"**

1. Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console. https://cloud.google.com/console/google/maps-apis/overview
2. Select your project with dropdown in top navigation bar.
3. Click on Menu and go to "APIs & Services" > "Library"
4. Activate "Maps SDK for Android" and "Maps SDK for iOS".
5. Then create new API key and add it to your project in `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `<application>` tag:

> ```
> <meta-data
>   android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
>   android:value="YOUR_ANDROID_KEY"/>
> ```